# Efficiency in writing to disk in Fortran

Tags: fortran, disk

I am trying to write a bunch of large matrices in fortran to disk. 
Matrices are `V`, `C` and `d`. All have size `(2 , n1, n2, n3, n4, n5).`

These are large matrices. And fortran is taking around 3 hours to write them.

```
do ind1=1,n1
do ind2=1,n2
do ind3=1,n3
do ind4=1,n4

     write(filename,'(a,i0,a,i0,a,i0,a,i0,a,i0,a)')'PF',t,'_',ind1,'_',ind2,'_',ind3,'_',ind4,'.txt'

     OPEN(UNIT=25,FILE=filename,STATUS='replace',ACTION='write')
     do ind5=1,n5
      WRITE(25,*) c(2,ind1,ind2,ind3, ind4,ind5)
     end do
     do ind5=1,n5
      WRITE(25,*) v(2,ind1,ind2,ind3, ind4,ind5)
     end do
     do ind5=1,n5
      WRITE(25,*) d(1,ind1,ind2,ind3, ind4,ind5)
     end do
     CLOSE(UNIT=25)

end do
end do
end do
end do
```

Any smart way of doing this faster?

Comment: How big are n[1-5]? Do you need all the separate files?

Comment: n1 = 201, n2 = 50,n3 = 2, n4 = 2, n5 = 21. 
The separate files are not essential if the speed improvement allows to write the data faster. However if possible I would like to keep them.

Comment: Do you *really* need the result as text? Text files will be always slow.

Comment: No. No need to have them as text. As long as I can load them with the same precision later in matlab anything works.

Comment: If you plan to still be using these files in, say, 6 months, it's probably worth your while starting now on the steep (at first) learning curve for HDF5.

Comment: I will be running this codes for the next years ... 
I will take a look at that. Any references that could be useful?

Comment: Hang on, LMGTFY ... :-)

Comment: NetCDF is an alternative to HDF5 which has a slightly less steep learning curve, at least IMO. Adios is also supposed to be pretty straightforward, but I've never used it myself.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark fair enough. :)

Comment: Apologies. Where it is 2 x n1 it should be 2, n1. Just corrected that.

Comment: If you use a compiler which has an option for buffered i/o, you should check that it is in effect.

Comment: FWIW you can very simply write in binary. You hardly change the code at all, just open `access=stream`.  I'm sure there isn't much more to it on the matlab side.  (You do of course need to take tare to use compatible types, but thats not a big deal)

Comment: As another perhaps relatively minor issue, consider reordering the indices of your arrays. If the 'ind5' values are being accessed together they should be stored near each other in the array, which in fortran means the first index.

Comment: Are you not happy with the present answer? If you want anything more you should tell us what do you expect. What kind of detail? Detail of what exactly?

Comment: Did you try the code in the answer? Was it faster? How much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I agree with the comments, the best way would be to move to something like HDF5 or NetCDF which should give you both the portability of the data and also high performance.

That said if you want to stick with simple Fortran I/O it's usually a good idea to keep the number of I/O transactions to a minimum. I suspect all your opens are not a good idea, I would stick it all in one file. If that's OK you then have 3 routes as shown below and run on my laptop (which admittedly has a SSD). Anyway it should give you some ideas.

```
ian-admin@agon ~/test $ cat io.f90
Program test_io

  Implicit None

  Integer, Parameter :: wp = Selected_real_kind( 12, 70 )

  Integer, Parameter :: n1 = 201
  Integer, Parameter :: n2 = 50
  Integer, Parameter :: n3 = 2
  Integer, Parameter :: n4 = 2
  Integer, Parameter :: n5 = 21

  Real( wp ), Dimension( 1:2, 1:n1, 1:n2, 1:n3, 1:n4, 1:n5 ) :: stuff

  Integer :: start, finish, rate

  Integer :: i1, i2, i3, i4, i5

  Call Random_Number( stuff )

  Call System_Clock( start, rate )
  Do i1 = 1, n1
     Do i2 = 1, n2
        Do i3 = 1, n3
           Do i4 = 1, n4
              Do i5 = 1, n5
                 Write( 10, * ) stuff( 1, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5 )
              End Do
           End Do
        End Do
     End Do
  End Do
  Call System_Clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Loops : ', Real( finish - start ) / Real( rate )

  Call System_Clock( start, rate )
  Write( 11, * ) stuff( 1, :, :, :, :, : )
  Call System_Clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Array : ', Real( finish - start ) / Real( rate )

  Call System_Clock( start, rate )
  Write( 12 ) stuff( 1, :, :, :, :, : )
  Call System_Clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Unform: ', Real( finish - start ) / Real( rate )

End Program test_io
ian-admin@agon ~/test $ gfortran -O -Wall -Wextra -std=f2003 io.f90
ian-admin@agon ~/test $ ./a.out
 Loops :    2.28500009    
 Array :    1.80200005    
 Unform:    5.79999983E-02
ian-admin@agon ~/test $
```