# Accelerate a file writing routine in Fortran with OpenMP

Tags: io, fortran, openmp

I have a derived type `t_data` composed of three arrays : Velocity, Position and Acceleration

```
  type :: t_data

    real(kind=REAL64),   allocatable :: velocity(:)
    real(kind=REAL64),   allocatable :: position(:)
    real(kind=REAL64),   allocatable :: acceleration(:)

   end type t_data
```

I allocate those arrays and fill them with information. At some point I need to print that information in ASCII VTK format and I do the following :

```
 open(nfil,file=trim(fname)//'.vtk')

    write(nfil, '(a)') "Velocity"//" 3 "//trim(str(n_particle))//" double"
    do j=1, (n_particle)
        write(fileid, '(ES25.16E3, a, ES25.16E3, a, ES25.16E3, a)') (data%velocity(j+(j-1)*2)), " ", (data%velocity(j+(j-1)*2+1)), " ", (data%velocity(j+(j-1)*2+2)), " "
    end do

    write(nfil, '(a)') "Position"//" 3 "//trim(str(n_particle))//" double"
    do j=1, (n_particle)
        write(fileid, '(ES25.16E3, a, ES25.16E3, a, ES25.16E3, a)') (data%position(j+(j-1)*2)), " ", (data% position(j+(j-1)*2+1)), " ", (data% position(j+(j-1)*2+2)), " "
    end do

    write(nfil, '(a)') "Acceleration"//" 3 "//trim(str(n_particle))//" double"
    do j=1, (n_particle)
        write(fileid, '(ES25.16E3, a, ES25.16E3, a, ES25.16E3, a)') (data%acceleration(j+(j-1)*2)), " ", (data% acceleration(j+(j-1)*2+1)), " ", (data% acceleration(j+(j-1)*2+2)), " "
    end do

  close(nfil)
```

My question is : Is there a way I could accelerate that file writing routine with OpenMP ?

I tried to use OpenMP to accelerate the `DO` loops on `j` but I need the output to be ordered. So when I used the `ORDERED` OpenMP keyword, it compiles and runs but I have no speed up at all since all the threads perform the write operation in order and one by one.

Is there a way for example to use three threads and make them write the content of each array at the right location in the file in parallel ?

Comment: Probably not, the bottleneck will be the filesystem and most can't handle multiple transactions at once as ultimately they only have one "disk" underneath them (I think, not totally sure about solid state) - unless you've invested in RAID or something more expensive like lustre. But your I/O is probably done horribly inefficiently - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637321/efficiency-in-writing-to-disk-in-fortran/43639246#43639246

Comment: ASCII output is slow and always will be. Use binary, write large pieces at once, and it will be *much* faster without any parallelism.

Comment: @IanBush it's also worth pointing out that there's a  good chance that the Fortran runtime will serialize internally when doing formatted I/O...

Comment: Yes, good point @JimCownie - the "ultimately" in my comment was a vague attempt to cover such things, but you are right, being more explicit is useful here.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I'll try to switch to binary.