# Fortran best way to improve write to file speed for large arrays

Tags: optimization, fortran, gfortran

I have a very large array size of 20,000,000 that I would like to write to a file, unformatted.
It is an autocorrelation function.

It is pretty quick using the -O4 optimization compilation flag without the writing to file.
But as soon as i write to file it seems like it would take over a day to finish.

At the end is the f90 program. Below is the outputs without writing to file and with writing to file.

It's clear that writing single element of an array takes around 10ms.

20,000,000 x 0.01 = 200,000 seconds = 3,333 minutes = 55 hrs

How is it possible that it takes this long to write to a file when reading only takes 45 seconds? And what can I do to improve the speed?

**Notes**

System: Ubuntu 20.04

Compilation line: fortran -o acorr.exe -O4 acorr.f90

**No File Write**

```
elapsed time for reading:    43.4389992    
 Size of Jx:     20000000
 Loop Start Time:    43.5009995    
 correlation time magnitude 1e0 elapsed time:    43.5009995    
 correlation time magnitude 1e1 elapsed time:    43.5009995    
 correlation time magnitude 1e2 elapsed time:    43.5009995    
 correlation time magnitude 1e3 elapsed time:    43.5009995    
 correlation time magnitude 1e4 elapsed time:    43.5009995    
 correlation time magnitude 1e5 elapsed time:    43.5009995    
 correlation time magnitude 1e6 elapsed time:    43.5029984    
 correlation time magnitude 1e7 elapsed time:    43.5190010    
 elapsed time:    43.5369987
```

**With File Write**

```
 elapsed time for reading:    43.6349983    
 Size of Jx:     20000000
 Loop Start Time:    43.6949997    
 correlation time magnitude 1e0 elapsed time:    43.7319984    
 correlation time magnitude 1e1 elapsed time:    43.8969994    
 correlation time magnitude 1e2 elapsed time:    45.4980011    
 correlation time magnitude 1e3 elapsed time:    61.5289993
```

**acorr.f90**

```
PROGRAM acorr
    
    real:: a,b,c,d, sum, mean, var
    integer:: i,j, jsize,beginning, rate, end, end1
    real, dimension(20000000):: Jx, Jxm, corr
    integer:: skip_lines = 4
    call system_clock(beginning, rate)
    
    !reading file
    open(10, file='DiamHeat.log', status='old')
    do i = 1,skip_lines
        read(10,*)
    end do
    do i = 1, 20000000
        read(10,*) a, b, Jx(i), c, d
    end do
    call system_clock(end)
    print *, "elapsed time for reading: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
    close(10)
    !finished reading

    open(20, file='acorr.txt', form='UNFORMATTED')
    jsize = size(Jx)
    print *, "Size of Jx: ", jsize
    !print *, dot_product(Jx(10:jsize),Jx(1:jsize-10))

    !calculate mean
    mean = sum(Jx)/jsize
    Jxm(:) = Jx(:)-mean

    !calculate variance
    var = dot_product(Jxm,Jxm)/jsize
    
    !begin autocorrelation calc
    call system_clock(end1)
    print *, "Loop Start Time: ", real(end1 - beginning) / real(rate)
    do i =0,jsize-1
        !calculation
        corr(i+1) = dot_product(Jxm(i+1:jsize),Jxm(1:jsize-i))/var/(jsize-i)

        !clock timing
        if(i == 1) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e0 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
        else if(i == 10) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e1 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
        else if(i == 100) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e2 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
        else if(i == 1000) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e3 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
        else if(i == 10000) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e4 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
        else if(i == 100000) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e5 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
        else if(i == 1000000) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e6 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
        else if(i == 10000000) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e7 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
        end if 

    end do
    
    write(20,*) corr
    close(20)
    call system_clock(end)
    print *, "elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
END PROGRAM
```

Comment: `write(20,*) corr` is _formatted_ writing, not unformatted. That's not consistent with your open statement. Further, that write doesn't happen in the iterations of the loops, so are you sure of what you see?

Comment: Tried with fromatted and unformatted, doesn't change anything. And yes, this is what I see. Most likely it's due to the -On optimization compiler but i'm not sure.

Comment: The -On option will almost certainly make almost no difference to I/O speeds. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637321/efficiency-in-writing-to-disk-in-fortran/43639246#43639246 and see if it helps.

Comment: @ddwong What, precisely, do you mean by "Tried with fromatted and unformatted"? Did you try an unformatted write statement, or just change the open statement?

Comment: Without the output of `corr` at the end, the compiler may well decide (particularly at high optimization levels) not to bother doing the calculation of those values. You can maybe do a `print *, sum(corr)` at the end to have a look at that effect.

Comment: @francescalus was correct. Looks like the compiler is throwing away my array since it is not used. Adding the print statement at the end puts everything back together and the calculation just takes a long while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @francescalus commented, the compiler seems to be skipping over doing the calculation unless it is used for another purpose.
Adding the

```
print*, sum corr
```

after the loop seems to make the program compute the dot product in the loop. This just takes a long time but it is computing at best capacity.

Thanks again @francescalus